# How to get data from previos year?

Tags: sql, postgresql, lag

Here my base sample
I need get data from previous period with lag in Hello table

Could you help me?

```
+------+--------+------+-------+
| Year | Animal | Plus | Hello |
+-------+------+--------+------+
|    2 | Cat    |    3 |       |
|    2 | Dog    |    4 |       |
|    2 | Mouse  |    5 |       |
|    3 | Cat    |    5 |     3 |
|    3 | Dog    |    6 |     4 |
|    3 | Mouse  |    6 |     5 |
|    3 | Horse  |    6 |       |
|    3 | Pig    |    6 |       |
|    3 | Goose  |    6 |       |
|    4 | Cat    |      |     5 |
|    4 | Dog    |      |     6 |
|    4 | Mouse  |      |     6 |
|    4 | Horse  |      |     6 |
|    4 | Pig    |      |     6 |
+-------+------+--------+------+
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: What if a year is missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `LAG`. This function looks into previous rows.

```
select
  place, year, animal, plus,
  lag(plus) over (partition by animal order by year) as hello
from mytable
order by year, animal;
```

The "previous" row is the closest previous one, i.e. if for ' Goose' there are rows for year 3 and 5 and none for year 4, then year 3 would be considered the previous row for year 5 and `LAG` would show that value.

If you really want the adjacent previous year, i.e. year - 1, then you can select this year as follows:

```
select
  place, year, animal, plus,
  (
    select plus
    from mytable prev_year
    where prev_year.animal = mytable.animal
    and prev_year.year = mytable.year - 1)
  ) as hello
from mytable
order by year, animal;
```

Same thing with an outer join:

```
select
  t.place, t.year, t.animal, t.plus, prev_year.plus as hello
from mytable t
left join mytable prev_year on prev_year.animal = t.animal
                           and prev_year.year = t.year - 1
order by t.year, t.animal;
```

Comment: I see now that you even tagged your request with `lag`. If you already knew about the function, why didn't you just use it? (And even without `LAG` this is a quite simple task. You could have written a subquery or an outer join to get the value as shown in my answer.) Have you even tried to solve this yourself?

Comment: Everythig all right! I used lag without partition in my attempts. That was the reason. You code after some corrections was used in my real query. I mean this string of code "lag(plus) over (partition by animal order by year) as hello" Big Thank u!!!

Comment: You are welcome. One thing that just comes to mind: If there are gaps, say, for 'Goose' there are years 3 and 5 only, then `LAG` would show the year 3 value in the year 5 row. This may or may not be what you want. If you want to show null instead, because year 4 is missing, then either use one of the other queries or use `case when lag(year) over (partition by animal order by year) = year - 1 then lag(plus) over (partition by animal order by year) end`. I'd probably use the outer join query in that case.